# .addHitRegion() doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas

I have the latest Chrome version and I see in specs that it should support `.addHitRegion()` method, as mentioned on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/addHitRegion). For some reason I get `Uncaught TypeError: context.addHitRegion is not a function` error.

My code is as simple as this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.rect(10,10,100,100);
context.fill();
context.addHitRegion({'id': 'The First Button', 'cursor': 'pointer'});
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Oh sh..., seems like it was introduced more than 3 years ago and still experimental? I didn't even think it could still be not stable. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5):

Go here with your browser: **chrome://flags**

and then

> Set the flag **Experimental Web Platform features** to true to enable it.

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers states, you can enable this through flags, however: you won't be able to ask your users to do the same. And the support is limited to a few browsers. I would therefor recommend looking to other solutions - I list some here:

A notch better approach is to use [`Path2D` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D). They provide the same flexibility in terms of defining hit shapes. Use these with [`isPointInPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) which also takes a path object. Store each path in an array which you loop through using the position to test with. Unfortunately though, also this is limited to a few browsers, but you can at least use a [poly-fill such as this](https://github.com/google/canvas-5-polyfill) to fix that to some extend (see notes in the link for limitations).

A better option perhaps in regards to support and availability, and the one requiring a bit more work, is to rebuild each single path you want to test on the context itself, then use as above the `isPointInPath()` to see if the mouse position is inside that path.

If the shapes are simple such as rectangles or circles, you can do simple mathematical tests which is a performant alternative.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to set the experimental flag here

From The compatibility table at the bottom of the page you linked:

> This feature is behind a feature flag. Set the flag
>   ExperimentalCanvasFeatures to true to enable it.

To turn on experimental canvas features browse to “chrome://flags“, turn on “Enable experimental canvas features” and relaunch.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the hit region feature is now obsolete and doesn't appear to be enable-able. You can use isPointInPath() as an alternative. You'll need to create a path object to be able to pass into that function. Something like:

```
  const rectangle = new Path2D();
  ctx.beginPath();
  rectangle.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
  ctx.fill(rectangle);
```

...then to check, you could put it into an event listener:

```
 canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      if (ctx.isPointInPath(rectangle, e.offsetX, e.offsetY)) {
      console.log("rectangle is hit");
    });
```